# Is it possible to find only parent in Xpath from child?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML, is it possible to find only the title "Harry Potter" without the child "HP"?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter
   <alt_title lang="br">HP</alt_title>
</title>
  <price currency = "usd">29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price currency="gbp">39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

I tried `//alt_title[text() = "HP"]/parent::title`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following XPath expression.

```
/bookstore/book/title[alt_title="HP"]/text()[1]
```